# Call event when scroll to bottom of ScrollView component in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a question.
How to call a function when scroll down bottom of ScrollView in react native?
Please help me.
Thank so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It worked!

```
var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
          height = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
          offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
if( windowHeight + offset >= height ){
    console.log('End Scroll')
}
```

Comment: Works great. Don't forget to `import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'`

Comment: where does the e variable come from?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a function to `onScroll` prop of `ScrollView`.

More info can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this._onScroll = this._onScroll.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      contentOffsetY: 0
    }
  }

_onScroll(e){
    var contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    this.state.contentOffsetY < contentOffset ? console.log("Scroll Down") : console.log("Scroll Up");
    this.setState({contentOffsetY: contentOffset});
  }

  render(){
    var items = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
    return(
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} onScroll={this._onScroll}>
        {items.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={i} style={{height: 200}}>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Melih Mucuk. But how do i know i'm in bottom of ScrollView (end of ScrollView). Thanks you.

Comment: there is an prop called "contentSize" in e.nativeEvent. Why dont you log it and see whats come from this? You should compare contentOffsetY and contentSizeY. For example (contentSizeY - contentOffsetY) < 100, there are only 100 pixels to end of the scrollview. @jackmin

Comment: var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
            height = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
            offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        if( windowHeight + offset >= height ){
            console.log('End ScrollView')
        }

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use these two methods of ScrollView full and final. Do not use ónScroll' because it will call many times on a single scroll.

```
onStartScrollList = () => {
    this.setState({ isListScrolled: true });
    console.log('onScrollList');
}

onStopScrollList = () => {
    console.log('onStopScrollList');
    this.setState({ isListScrolled: false });

}
```

Now check 'isListScrolled' in your 'loadMore' method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the **scrollToEnd** event in a component, you can try the following method as an alternative

```
import { ScrollView, NativeScrollEvent } from 'react-native';

const someScrollAction = (event: NativeScrollEvent) => {

    const layoutMeasurementHeight = +event.layoutMeasurement.height.toFixed(3);
    const contentHeight = +event.contentSize.height.toFixed(3);
    const contentOffset = +event.contentOffset.y.toFixed(3);
    const totalHeight = +(layoutMeasurementHeight + contentOffset).toFixed(3);

    if (totalHeight >= contentHeight) {
        console.log('Scroll to end');
    }
}

<ScrollView
    onScroll={ (event) => someScrollAction(event.nativeEvent) }>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```